# VS code keep showing red underline when there's nothing wrong with the code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

my VS code keeps showing the red underline as if there's anything wrong with my code when I pasted or delete some console or comment, which is weird because the red underline is running all over the place. look at the image below to see what it looks like.

[image: Description]

this error doesn't affect my code but it's annoying to see the red underline everywhere.
i'm seeking for a solution, does anyone ever meet this error? and how to fix it?

Comment: Save file, close VS and reopen? Maybe it helps xD

Comment: I think it's because of some linting issues.

Comment: What does VSDC say the error is when you mouse over it?

Comment: @MaraBlack lol, of course, this would help but who would close and reopen the application all the time?

Comment: @SRana yes, but do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @TechGnome 
',' expected. ts(1005) [1114, 7]
',' expected. ts(1005) [1114, 11]
')' expected. ts(1005) [1114, 43]
like this and so on but the thing is the nothing to add not parenthesis nor comma to be added, the errors are just everywhere

Comment: @sarah, i have faced this issue few months ago. I have uninstalled and installed latest vscode which resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seldom occurs when your code has large trunks of unsaved changes.
Just save your code once and you are good to go.